# Find Average Value based on Date and SKU

Tags: microsoft-excel, query

I come with another question.

I am trying to find the last purchase price per SKU.

I have the list of SKUs I want to find the pricing for in `Column A` of `Sheet 1`. In `Sheet 2` I have the SKU in `Column E`, the purchase date in `Column D`, and the purchase price in `Column J`.

My data is organized in such a way that SKUs can be purchased multiple times at the same price and at the same time. So I figured a `=AVERAGEIFS` function would do the trick, but I am getting `DIV/0` error.

This is what I have so far.

`=AVERAGEIFS('Sheet 2'!$J:$J,'Sheet 2'!$E:$E,$A2,'Receiving Invoice Report'!$D:$D,MAX('Sheet 2'!$D:$D))`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MAX('Sheet 2'!$D:$D)` returns one value, the latest date in that column without regards to what sku. As such, the date is not being found in relation to the sku and you are return a null array to the AVERAGEIFS.

You will need to replace that With MAXIFS():

```
MAXIFS('Sheet 2'!$D:$D,'Sheet 2'!$E:$E,$A2)
```

ie:

```
=AVERAGEIFS('Sheet 2'!$J:$J,'Sheet 2'!$E:$E,$A2,'Receiving Invoice Report'!$D:$D,MAXIFS('Sheet 2'!$D:$D,'Sheet 2'!$E:$E,$A2))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Scott! You are as helpful as always.